# How to close a window after running each test case in Selenium IntelliJ?

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea

I have a set of three test cases, and I want to avoid keeping open multiple browser windows since I automated this process in Selenium. Is there a way to close a browser after each test case is finished without giving an error?

Using close() and quit() both give me error codes of 1.

Comment: Post sample code of you starting the browser and attempting to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use below approach to handle these issue.

1) create a base class which has beforeSuite , beforeTest , afterTest , afterSuite methods which will run always.

2) Each test plan should extend this class to create driver and close the driver.

BasePage.java

```
 package com.test.test3;

 import java.lang.reflect.Method;
 import java.util.Date;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
 import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;


public class BasePage {

public WebDriver driver = null;

private Date start;

/*
 * Below method will initialize the driver once test method started
 * execution
 */
public void initializeDriver(WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver = driver;

}

/*
 * Below method will kill driver
 */
public void tearDown() {

    if (this.driver != null) {
        this.driver.quit();
    }

}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterTestMethod(Method method) {

    // Clean ups for test level services
    tearDown();

}

@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterTestSuite() {

    tearDown();

}


}
```

Testplan.java

```
package com.test.test3;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestPlan extends BasePage{

@Test(groups = { "test"})
public void test() {

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    System.out.println("TestAutomation test");
}

@Test(groups = { "test"})
public void test1() {
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    System.out.println("TestAutomation test");
}

@Test(groups = { "test"})
public void test2() {
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    System.out.println("TestAutomation test");
}

}
```

testNg.xml

```
<suite name="API TEST CASES">

<test name="api test" parallel="methods">

    <groups>

        <run>
            <include name="test" />
        </run>

    </groups>

    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.test3.TestPlan" />
    </classes>

</test>
```